# In Gitlab CICD, dotenv not available in next job RULE:IF section

Tags: git, gitlab, devops, cicd

How do i pass variable with dynamic value from one job to other job to be used in RULE:IF section and not in usual SCRIPTS section?

```
job1:
  script:
    - echo "MY_VAR=someval" >> .env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: .env

job2:
  rule:
    - if: $MY_VAR == "someval"
  script:
    - echo "Executed job2"
```

gitlab cicd clearly stated that **dotenv variables wont work in rule:if section**. In this situation, how do we get the value from previous job for rule:if section?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to achieve. Skipping a job based on a previous job output is, of course, always possible with the exit value. But this will leads to pipeline failures which I think you don`t want.

But you may skip a job while keeping it shown in the pipeline (as succeeded!) with something like this

```
job1:
  script:
    - echo "MY_VAR=someval" >> .env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: .env

job2:
  rule:
    - if: $MY_VAR == "someval"
  script:
    - if [[ "$MY_VAR" == "someval" ]]; echo "skip"; exit 0; fi
    - echo "Executed job2"
```